base conversion by "uniform groupwise replacements" where the decimal point does not separate two groups (in the representation w.r.t the old base)
Let me start with an example.
Say I want to find the representation w.r.t. base $8$ of a (real) number $x$ already represented w.r.t. base $4$. For example, let $x := 31220.1033_4$. You could convert $x$ to decimal ($x=872.30859375_{10}$) and then convert this to base $8$ with the Greedy algorithm (i.e., how many times (the digit $d_3$) does $8^3$ go into $x$, then how many times (the digit $d_2$) does $8^2$ go into $x-d_3 8^3$, and so on). This gives $x = 1550.236_8$.
However, the bases $4$ and $8$ being powers of $2$ allows one to obtain the result quicker by "uniform groupwise replacement": Grouping the digits w.r.t. the old base $4$ into groups of three (the decimal point separating two groups), converting each group as if it was its own number (yielding groups of two) and concatenating the results yields the desired representation if the decimal point is placed between the two new groups that were obtained from the old groups next to the decimal point.
I am interested in pairs of bases $(b_{old},b_{new})$ where such a "uniform groupwise replacement" (old groups all have the same length, new groups all have the same length, equal groups become equal groups plus some rule for the relative position of the groups and the decimal points) can be used for conversion.
Here is another (more interesting) example, which requires "non-integer bases". All you need to know for this is: Any real number $b > 1$ can be a base. The digits are $0,\ldots,\lceil b \rceil -1$. Given digits $\ldots,d_1,d_0,d_{-1},\ldots$ with $d_p = 0$ for all $p$ sufficiently large, the series $\sum_p d_p b^p$ converges, and every non-negative real number can be the limit of such a series (the digit sequence is not unique in general though).
Now consider the real polynomial $2X^3-X^2-X-1$. It has only one real root $b$. This is the new base. The old base is $b^4$. You can check that $1 < b < 2$ and $2 < b^4 < 3$ (hence the digits are 0,1,2 for the old base and 0,1 for the new base). You can also check that the following uniform groupwise replacement really works: Groups of one become groups of four. More precisely: 0 becomes 0000, 1 becomes 1000 and 2 becomes 0111. The new decimal point is placed between the two left-most digits of the group obtained from the digit to the left of the old decimal point.
Example: $20.1_{b^4} = 01110.0001000_b = 1110.0001_b$
So this is a base pair where the new decimal point does not separate two groups.
My question is: Is there a base pair allowing such a uniform groupwise replacement s.t. the old decimal point does not separate two groups (and s.t. there is no uniform groupwise replacement where it does)?
I believe that it is more likely that such a pair does not exist. If such a pair existed, the old group length $l_{old}$ must be at least two obviously. Let $l_{new}$ be the new group size. One can show that it must be $b_{old}^{l_{old}} = b_{new}^{l_{new}}$. In search for a pair, I fixed $l_{old}$ and $l_{new}$ (small numbers at first). The above equality shows that $b_{new}$ is dependent on $b_{old}$, hence the only task is finding a good $b_{old}$. During my search, it seemed that the problem has to do with polynomials with integer coefficients. This is how I found the example using the polynomial from above. The problem is: There I only needed to find numbers solving one polynomial equation of a certain type (the coefficients depending on the available digits), and the existence of these numbers followed quickly with the intermediate value theorem. Here it seems that I need numbers satisfying multiple (at least $4$, and the number of equations explodes with growing $l_{old}$ and/or $b_{old}$) such polynomial equations simultaneously. And this seems really unlikely to me.
When I proved another result about this, I used some facts about irreducibility of polynomials, so I believe someone with better knowledge about polynomials could help here. That is why I also used the polynomials tag.
Thanks for reading all of this! I am very interested to see if someone here already thought about this in the past. Best-case scenario would be someone finding a base pair that works. A proof that such a pair does not exist would also be great, of course. :D I can describe my attempts so far in the comments in more detail if needed.
